# Swift transition animation does not work when subclassing UIView

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, subclass

When applying this animation to a UIView, UIButton or UILabel after connecting it to my ViewController and calling from ViewDidAppear, it works fine:

```
 UIView.transition(with: self.myButton, duration: 5, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: nil, completion: nil)
```

However, the problem is, when I input that animation in a custom class inheriting from UIView, set it to that object in my storyboard, and pass "self" into the "with:" parameter, and put it on AwakeFromNib, it does not work:

```
class myAnimatedView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
         self.layoutIfNeeded()
         UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 15, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: nil, completion: nil)}
    }

}
```

Other animations I have applied work fine on AwakeFromNib on such a subclass -
 for example this  works fine :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 5.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)), animations:({//my animations here}))
```

What am I doing wrong? Using Xcode 9.1, Swift 4. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some problems in your code/architecture:

1. awakeFromNib is not that right place for triggering animations, please check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib)
2. you say that adding this

   ```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 5.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)), animations:({//my animations here}))
   ```

   in your awakeFromNib was fine, but I notice a delay of 0.5 so the view was ready and well awakened when the animation was being launched

---

eventually you might use didMoveToWindow() for auto-animate your stuff
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622527-didmovetowindow

Comment: Thanks for your reply - reason I want it in AwakeFromNib is coz I have probably 100 UI elements in 25 view controllers and want them to animate into position with some fancy animations when user loads each VC. Rest of animations work fine when view appears apart from this - is there another method apart from AwakeFromNib that woud achieve this?

Comment: I see, you might try to move your animation logic inside didMoveToWindow()